# When did Batman get a Green Lantern Power Ring?

Tags: dc, batman, green-lantern

What is this panel from? I tried googling it, but I just got people arguing about how powerful this combination would be, or why it hasn't happened yet.

[image: Batman stands atop a gargoyle, with a glowing green power ring, and a holographic green bat with a lantern symbol on his chest.]

The only thing I can think of is the 1994 Elseworlds series 'Darkest Knight', mentioned [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14668/if-batman-has-such-strong-will-power-why-hasnt-he-been-recruited-by-the-lanter#comment27053_14668). I haven't been able to link the two.

Comment: What makes you think it's a genuine panel, and not some fan art?

Comment: @Flimzy Intuition from reading comics. Plus, if I was making fan art I'd have drawn him beating someone up....

Comment: He'd make a better yellow lantern :-)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m91TWszZUfw

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Ans: [Green Lantern Vol 4 #9](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Vol_4_9)**

You can see a variant cover here with the same picture:

[image]

Batman does not get his own ring. He temporarily borrows Hal Jordan's as an attempt at psychotherapy. Nor is the cover a piece of fan art. It was actually an alternate cover to the issue Green Lantern Vol 4, #9, "Branded" by Geoff Johns. The cover was done by Ethan Van Sciver.

> "Branded" - Batman calls on Green Lantern to take on a new version of an old foe - the Tattooed Man. This one is in the Cityside Motel in Gotham City, and has been murdering people, including Lou Rosen who was cheating on his wife. While Green Lantern takes on his tattoos, Batman takes out the man himself. Back in the Batcave, Hal has Bruce try on the ring, to try and help him overcome his inner demons. Bruce conjurs up images of bats a first, but then gains control and forms a vision of his parents. Batman tells him he's not ready to give up his darkness, but thanks anyway and they part ways.

Comment: How many comics have you read in your entire life? Any guess?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - `select * from all_comics`

Comment: @DVK: We'll have to test this.  Someone ask an 'Archie' question.

Comment: And this was quickly followed by Batman almost becoming a Yellow Lantern (to strike fear in the cowardly and superstitious criminals) and temporarily a white lantern.

Answer (score 9):

Batman is given a Green Lantern ring in [Batman : In Darkest Night](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_In_Darkest_Knight). It looks awesome!

According to wikipedia;

> The comic is an Elseworlds story in which Bruce Wayne becomes the
>   Green Lantern instead of Hal Jordan. This one change creates a domino
>   effect which changes many events and characters in the DC Universe.
>   The story draws heavily from related Batman comics, including Batman:
>   Year One and The Killing Joke.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy! It looks like your answer is quite anecdotal, do you have any more information to add? Here added references to the points you make would help back up your answer :) Also, have you taken the [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Answer (score -1):

I [faintly] recall that in one issue, [of the Dark Knight] Hal Jordan gave Batman his ring, “to try it out for size”, to see if not only would he want to join the ranks of being a Green Lantern, but a better introspection of himself.

He put the ring on and was immediately overwhelmed by the power of the ring, seeing visions of what he was in the past through to the present and gaining a more open insight of himself and what he regarded as his duties

Ultimately he refused the ring, giving it back to Hal and stating that: “**That's too much power for a human being to wield**”, then walking away in a sombre mood.

Comment: Can you add any referencing to this answer?