# Why doesn't Batman seek out a Yellow Lantern ring?

Tags: dc, batman, green-lantern

I've seen a page from a comic numerous times where Bruce Wayne is chosen as a Yellow Lantern, due to his ability to "instill great fear".  Here's half below (I couldn't find the first half, where the ring approaches him, but you get the idea).

[image]

Obviously, in this moment he's surprised and reacting by instinct.  The last panel makes it clear that he didn't even understand what was happening.

But it does raise the question, why doesn't Batman *seek out* a Yellow ring?  God knows he's ok with using fear as a weapon, and he's got the imagination and willpower to use a power ring well.  He's failed to measure up to being a Green Lantern because of his inability to get over the fear of losing his parents, but presumably the Yellow Corps wouldn't have such a requirement.

No doubt his friend Hal would have something to say about Batman working with Sinestro, but still, Batman and a Yellow ring seem like a match made in a terrifying, terrifying heaven.

Have we ever gotten any stated reason, in any canon, about why Batman doesn't want such a weapon, or why he doesn't consider it worth seeking out?  It seems like, for a fear-monger obsessed with gadgets and ultra-preparedness, a fear-based weapon capable of producing any gadget with a thought would be the ultimate expression of his own ideal.

Comment: Don't yellow rings take control over the wearers? Sinestro has some control over them.

Comment: Why does everyone assume that Yellow Lanterns are bad guys or working with Sinestro?  As you said, Batman already uses fear as his primary weapon and it would be a match made in heaven.  I highly doubt Batman would become evil if he wielded a yellow ring.  Pretty sure it rests on the person that wears the ring to decide whether he/she is evil.  Sinestro is a perfect example of this, he was a Green Lantern at one point, but still had the lust for power and committed highly questionable acts.  The yellow power battery didn't do these things to him.

Comment: Sorry, Robert, but I am going to have to disagree. The very premise of the Yellow Lantern Corps is that its members delight in their power to cause fear and suffering. As much as Batman uses fear as a weapon, he does not want people to suffer and Sinestro is not the poster child for "good deeds, done cheap." He subjugated his entire planet so that he could establish what he considered order. To Sinestro and members of his Corps, the ends justifies the means and this means doing whatever it takes to get the result you want. Even Batman has limits...

Comment: Isn't Batman one of the more evil good guys? Yes. He's on the side of law and order, but he has his own sense of law and order.

Comment: Can't be conjecture, not exactly lacking information if you read all the comics. Being a fictional character you have to go only on what has been published. It is, however, purely opinion-based. Each and every writer adds their own spin to any character so it can be because of any reason the writer wants. Trying to make readers accept the reasoning is the only challenge.

Comment: Well, then, what is the reason the writer wanted?

Comment: A Yellow Lantern not only uses fear as his weapon, he also succumbs to his own fear. Batman doesn't want to do such a thing.

Comment: I happened to hit this question immediately after [seeing this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51487/5490), which I presume has the "previous exposure to green lantern power ring" that's mentioned here.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Batman is a man who likes to understand his tools and weapons. Despite his experience with the Green Lanterns, he isn't likely to use a technology he does not completely understand and cannot completely predict. Knowing the yellow power ring has any connection to Sinestro is enough for Batman to steer completely clear of it, given Sinestro's history.

- Batman is a obsessed and detail-oriented man who likes to understand how any technology he uses functions. Just his knowledge of the origins of the yellow power ring being connected to Sinestro would be enough for him to NOT to risk using it except under extreme circumstances and for no longer than necessary.
- Batman does not believe superpowers are necessary to fight crime. He believes strongly in the idea that it is the man and the use of the mind, not the weapon that matters. Given the nature of the DC universe, if Bruce Wayne wanted superpowers he could likely invent them (and in some parallel universes, he does). **See: [Batman Beyond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond).**

**See Also: [How does Batman fight magic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21551/2765) and [Why doesn't Batman make an armored suit like Iron Man's?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16935/2765)**

Comment: I don't think that's correct. He could get a complete explanation at any time, from Hal Jordan or anyone else. In the past, he has used both Green (spinoff/alternate comics? not sure about the main universe) and Yellow Rings (new 52, "Forever Evil"). Your answer is mainly your opinion.

Comment: And your opinion is best served by posting your own answer. We are now both winners.

Answer (score 15):

Adding to existing answers, in the Forever Evil comic, issue 4, Batman indeed has a Yellow Ring on his disposal. He plans to use it against the "Green Lantern" criminal, the Power Ring. He puts on the ring, and is horribly defeated by the Power Ring who then easly destroys Batman's Yellow Ring.

Sinestro explains Batman's failure to be a worthwhile Yellow Lantern like this:

[image]

Batman failed because he didn't succumb to his fears. Appereantly that's a requirement. I don't know if it was literally stated in other comics, but I always thought that being scared of something was a prerequisite to be a Yellow Lantern, not only the ability to instill fear.

Answer (score 0):

The ring says: "Bruce Wayne, you will now be subjected to...", then he says "No!"

Sounds to me like Batman does not like the idea of being "subjected" to the ring.

Comment: But, as the last panel demonstrates, he didn't know what was happening.  He was reacting on instinct to what seemed like an attack.  It doesn't mean that, in a calmer moment, he wouldn't necessarily want such a device.

Answer (score 0):

There was a point where he possessed a yellow ring.  When asked by Robin what he didn't keep and use it, he stated simply, "not my style."

Comment: Do you recall which issue, title(s), or storyline this exchange occurred in?

Answer (score 0):

Batman uses gadgets made by Lucius for a reason. He trusts Lucius, and knows completely what he uses to make them, and what they can do.

On the other hand, Batman completely hates Sinestro. He doesn't trust him at all, and has no idea what a full power yellow lantern ring can do.

There are some things that Batman would push the limit to do, but having his fears exposed to everyone, and being taken under control by a fear ridden ring, is not something he would do.

Comment: Do you have any examples from canon that supports your points?

Answer (score -3):

Now i think sure, it would be a match made in heaven because instilling great fear into people of Gotham is not a problem.I mean you would think "Oh my god of course he would be great as a yellow lantern I mean, he is Batman after all". But I think that you got to look at the facts of this. Sure he would be good at instilling fear into people,but a WHOLE sector with billions on billions of people.He has only really patrolled a city not a whole sector.
So i really think that it would be hard for him to adapt.

I think he would not even bother finding because he had a simple answer,He hates Sinestro,
but if it is not the injustice universe then sure he has really never encountered Sinestro but only in the blackest night and brightest day series

Comment: This seems like pure conjecture.

Answer (score -4):

Batman does not inherently revel in others' fear and he has strict boundaries which he does not break. He rejects the ring because he knows what it is and that there is not supposed to be more than one at this time. This is the beginning of the Sinestro Corp. he told the Green Lantern at the time about this. Which leads into the blackest night.

He also suppresses his own fear to be Batman, because if he doesn't, he will die.

But the true answer is because he is Batman.

And the yellow ring entity parallax is evil.