# How many different types/colors of Lantern Rings has Batman had access to?

Tags: dc, batman

There have been a few comics and TV shows showing Batman wielding a Green Lantern power ring; this makes sense, considering the green rings are powered by will, and Batman is shown to have one of *the* most powerful human wills on Earth. He was also "given" a Black Lantern ring in the "Darkest Night" saga, and I believe a White Ring at the end of it.

**But has he been shown to make use of any others?** And if so, what were those rings and how effective was he?

Any scans of him using these abilities in-canon would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81122/why-doesnt-batman-seek-out-a-yellow-lantern-ring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Batman has used the Yellow Lantern Ring twice, once in the *Forever Evil* arc (*Forever Evil #4*) and once in *Green Lantern: Sinestro Corps War*

---

### Forever Evil #4:

Batman secretly hid the Yellow Lantern ring disguised as a Kryptonite ring. However when he tried to use it, he was easily overpowered by [Power Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Ring_(DC_Comics)).

[image]  [image]
 <sub>*Click images to enlarge*</sub>

### *Green Lantern: Sinestro Corps War*

Right before the events of the Sinestro Corps War, Sinestro sent of several Yellow Lantern rings to seek out wielders. One such ring found Batman. But his willpower was greater than the fear power thus the ring almost immediately rejected Batman.

[image]
 <sub>*Click image to enlarge*</sub>

---

### Batman has also wielded the Green Lantern ring several times

The list includes:

1. **Justice League: Darkseid War** by writer Geoff Johns. When Bruce is unable to stop using the Mobius Chair, Hal Jordan intervenes to eventually free him from the chair's grasp. Hal slips the ring into Batman's finger to only save and free Batman from the chair's hold on him. In this case, it was merely to free Batman so it may not count.

   [image]
    <sub>*Click image to enlarge*</sub>
2. **Batman: In Darkest Knight** by Mike W. Barr and Jerry Bingham, where Bruce Wayne was found worthy of the ring rather than Hal Jordan after the death of Abin Sur. So in this case, he is effective and powerful as any Green Lantern. This is an elseworld story arc.

   [image] [image]
    <sub>*Click images to enlarge*</sub>
3. **Dark Knights: Metal** by Scott Snyder and Greg Capullo where Bruce Wayne is once again chosen by the Green Lantern ring the night his parents were murdered. An interesting take where Bruce actually overpowers the ring's willpower unlocking the use of lethal force. He then dons a new name **Dawnbreaker**.

   [image]  [image]
    <sub>*Click images to enlarge*</sub>

---

### Finally Batman has wielded the Black and White Lantern rings once

Batman's corpse was reanimated and brought back to distorted life as a Black Lantern by Nekron and Black Hand.

[image] [image]
 <sub>*Click images to enlarge*</sub>

And finally, after the events of the *Blackest Night* story, in Issue #7, many dead heroes were brought back to life. But only **Deadman** was gifted with a White Lantern ring, choosing him as its guide as they went along seeking the champion of Earth as its host. Naturally, Deadman thought that the only person this champion could be was Batman.

When he found him, Deadman thrust the ring on the Caped Crusader, shouting that Batman would know what to do because Batman always knows what to do. But while Batman was able to wield the life-powered ring for a short amount of time, it also had a mind of its own and deemed that the burden of the white ring should not be on Bruce Wayne.

Comment: Quick tip, if you want to inline text/images to the bullet or numbered list above them add a space at the start of the line.

Comment: Another one, if you want to have a smaller image which does enlarge on click, set the image link to the `m` post fixed one and the click through link to the normal image rather than both as the `m`.

Comment: I was aware of _Dark knights: Metal_ and _Darkseid Wars,_ but the other was new to me. Thank you.